# Is it more efficient to create an object or repeatedly call accessor?

Tags: c#, performance

I'm new to c# and would like to know which is more efficient and what is considered best practice.

Say for example you are sent a `MouseEventArgs` and need to know where the mouse is multiple times in the method. Is it more efficient in terms of space and time to create a `Point` at the beginning of the method or continually call the X and Y accessors? Are there times when one approach is preferred over another?

Code Example:

```
private void table_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid.HitTestType htt = table.HitTest(new Point(e.X, e.Y)).Type;
    ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
    cm.Show(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

    //More methods requiring e.X and e.Y
}
```

vs

```
private void table_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point mousePosition = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    DataGrid.HitTestType htt = table.HitTest(mousePosition).Type;
    ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
    cm.Show(mousePosition);

    //More methods requiring mousePosition
}
```

Comment: Measure it. Profile your application and compare the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating the value once and reuse it is more efficient, but not by much.

In your example it will make no difference at all. Creating the context menu takes thousands times longer than creating the `Point` value, so you will never even be able to measure the difference.

As the performance isn't an issue here, consider which way would create more maintainable code. You will probably find that it's the code that creates the value once, as it's easier to read and reduces the risk that you get it wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It always depends. There are lots of factors you have to take in consideration. For instance, in this case `Point` is a value type that I presume is very lightweight to assemble in comparison with a reference type.

In any case, there isn't a golden rule other than **profile it**. If there's a noticeable difference, then stick with what's best for your scenario. If there's not, do as you like best.

Answer (score 0):

There's several things to consider in code quality. Among those some keys to keep in mind is maintenance, reuse of code, memory footprint.

For maintenance, reusing things, particularly literals and simply objects such as your Point object can save a great deal of time and heartache. Furthermore when you create an object it is basically a reference to its' properties. Therefore you can save, albeit a meager amount of memory by declaring such a point that isn't going to change across the algorithm.

Long story short it will be more beneficial to create a habit of reusing the same object, as appose to create new instances, (certain exception in mind you will encounter down the road) when possible.

**Note:**

Additionally as @Guffa pointed out there are certain objects such as Point that are from a struct and not a class and thus, like primitives like strings and numeric types will be sent by value (essentially copied) unless specifically sent by reference with the "ref" keyword.

Comment: Note: `Point` is a struct, not a class.

Comment: @Guffa Very good point, (no pun intended ;) ) I added additional information to my answer on structs verses classes.